# convert php associative array into javascript object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to load Chinese words as keys, and their English translations as values from a database into a php array so then I can use them on the client side in JavaScript. So I load the PHP key:value pairs into the JavaScript array and try to output the results as key value pair as such:

```
stuff : Ni, You 
stuff : Ta, Him or Her
stuff : Wo, I
```

Chinese and English words are loaded in a relational database.

**PHP**:

```
$wordsArray = array();               
while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
    $wordsArray[$row['chinese']] = $row['english'];
}
```

**Javascript**: Here I want the $.each to output the key as a string, and not a number index. So when I tried `var words = [<?php echo '"'.implode('","', $wordsArray).'"' ?>];` as an array, I got:

```
stuff : 0, You 
stuff : 1, Him or Her
stuff : 2, I
```

When I'm really looking for:

```
stuff : Ni, You 
stuff : Ta, Him or Her
stuff : Wo, I
```

So I changed `words` to be an object so that `$.each` could output key as string:

```
var words = {<?php echo '"'.implode('","', $wordsArray).'"' ?>};
$.each(words, function(key, value) {
    console.log('stuff : ' + key + ", " + value);
});
```

Which throws error: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,`

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can use [json_encode()](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to make `array` as an `json object` like,

```
var words = <?php echo json_encode($wordsArray) ?>;// don't use quotes
$.each(words, function(key, value) {
    console.log('stuff : ' + key + ", " + value);
});
```

Comment: `var dp1 = <?php echo json_encode( $dataPoints1 ) ?>;

console.log(dp1);` still gives me Array to string conversion error can you please see my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61280217/8919244) related to it ?

Comment: Very important don't forget the semi-colon at the end of the php closing tag `?>;`.  Otherwise you will receive an error `SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier`.

Answer (score 7):

For me the simplest way to convert php array to javascript object is to json_encode the php array then JSON.parse it from javascript like this:

```
<?php 
    $array = [1 => "one", 2 => "two", 3 => "three"];
?>

<script>
    const jsObject = JSON.parse(`<?= json_encode($array) ?>`)
    console.log(jsObject) // Object { 1: "one", 2: "two", 3: "three" }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

I looked a lot for an elegant solution to fix this issue without doing changing things over javascript or just replace quotes via preg_replace (for the case that the values would contain quotes) and end up doing it by myself. even if it's too late, I hope it would help those who are looking for the same solution.

```
function json_encode_advanced(array $arr, $sequential_keys = false, $quotes = false, $beautiful_json = false) {

    $output = "{";
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {

        if ( isAssoc($arr) || (!isAssoc($arr) && $sequential_keys == true ) ) {
            $output .= ($quotes ? '"' : '') . $key . ($quotes ? '"' : '') . ' : ';
        }

        if (is_array($value)) {
            $output .= json_encode_advanced($value, $sequential_keys, $quotes, $beautiful_json);
        } else if (is_bool($value)) {
            $output .= ($value ? 'true' : 'false');
        } else if (is_numeric($value)) {
            $output .= $value;
        } else {
            $output .= ($quotes || $beautiful_json ? '"' : '') . $value . ($quotes || $beautiful_json ? '"' : '');
        }

        if (++$count < count($arr)) {
            $output .= ', ';
        }
    }

    $output .= "}";

    return $output;
}

function isAssoc(array $arr) {
    if (array() === $arr) return false;
    return array_keys($arr) !== range(0, count($arr) - 1);
}
```

usage:

```
$array = [
    'someField' => '"value"', // double quotes for string if needed
    'labelField' => '"label"', // double quotes for string if needed
    'boolean' => false,
    'numeric' => 5,
    'render' => [
        'option' => 'function() {
            console.log("Hello World!");
            console.log(\'Hello World!\');
        }',
    ],
];
echo json_encode_advanced($array);
```

result:

```
{
    someField : "value",
    labelField : "label",
    boolean : false,
    numeric : 5,
    render : {
        option : function() {
            console.log("Hello World!");
            console.log('Hello World!');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer of Rohan Kumar is excellent except it uses jQuery to show the results.

This can be quicker and easier:

```
var words = <?php echo json_encode( $wordsArray ) ?>;
console.dir(words);
```

This gives you a one line result like <kbd>`Object ▶`</kbd>. Clicking on the `▶` will open the object and shows its contents.

Comment: `var dp1 = <?php echo json_encode( $dataPoints1 ) ?>;

console.log(dp1);` still gives me Array to string conversion error can you please see my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61280217/8919244) related to it ?

Answer (score 2):

I just changed a few things to make it more compatible (line 3 and 29):

```
function json_encode_advanced(array $arr, $sequential_keys = false, $quotes = false, $beautiful_json = false) {

    $output = isAssoc($arr) ? "{" : "[";
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {

        if (isAssoc($arr) || (!isAssoc($arr) && $sequential_keys == true )) {
            $output .= ($quotes ? '"' : '') . $key . ($quotes ? '"' : '') . ' : ';
        }

        if (is_array($value)) {
            $output .= json_encode_advanced($value, $sequential_keys, $quotes, $beautiful_json);
        }
        else if (is_bool($value)) {
            $output .= ($value ? 'true' : 'false');
        }
        else if (is_numeric($value)) {
            $output .= $value;
        }
        else {
            $output .= ($quotes || $beautiful_json ? '"' : '') . $value . ($quotes || $beautiful_json ? '"' : '');
        }

        if (++$count < count($arr)) {
            $output .= ', ';
        }
    }

    $output .= isAssoc($arr) ? "}" : "]";

    return $output;
}
```