# How to pass an php associative array as argument to Javascript function with json_encode()

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I can sucessfully pass an index array to the javascript function with below code. For example:

```
<?php
$arr = array(1, 2, 3);
?>
<button onclick="test(<?=json_encode($arr)?>);">test</button>
<script>
function test(x){
  alert(x[0]);
  alert(x[1]);
  alert(x[2]);
}
</script>
```

Now I want to change the array to be an associative array. However, it doesn't work any more...

Is there any problem with my code ?

How should I fix it? Thank you very much !

My code is as below:

```
<?php
$arr = [ "A" => 1, "B" => 2, "C" => 3 ];
?>
<button onclick="test(<?=json_encode($arr)?>);">test</button>
<script>
function test(x){
  alert(x["A"]);
  alert(x["B"]);
  alert(x["C"]);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert php associative array into javascript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21153805/convert-php-associative-array-into-javascript-object)

Comment: @AlexanderNied Its answer is use json_encode(), which is just what  I'm trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quotes in the generated JSON confuse the html parser. You need to entity encode the contents of tag attributes. You can use `htmlspecialchars()` or `htmlentities()` for this:

```
<?php
$arr = [ "A" => 1, "B" => 2, "C" => 3 ];
?>
<button onclick="test(<?=htmlentities(json_encode($arr))?>);">test</button>
<script>
function test(x){
  alert(x["A"]);
  alert(x["B"]);
  alert(x["C"]);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion ! But the alert message shows "undefine". It doesn't show the value of the array...

Comment: Strange - its working perfectly for me. Can you view source in your browser and share?

Comment: Oops...sorry ....  I just got a typo... It works now !!!!
Thank you so much !!!!!!!!!