# Array to string conversion while using canvas js in yii2

Tags: javascript, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, canvasjs, jsonencoder

I am trying to load a chart on my index page in `yii2 project`. Below is my code

```
<?PHP

$dataPoints1 = array(
array("label"=> "2010", "y"=> 36.12),
array("label"=> "2011", "y"=> 34.87),
array("label"=> "2012", "y"=> 40.30),
array("label"=> "2013", "y"=> 35.30),
array("label"=> "2014", "y"=> 39.50),
array("label"=> "2015", "y"=> 50.82),
array("label"=> "2016", "y"=> 74.70)
);
$dataPoints2 = array(
array("label"=> "2010", "y"=> 64.61),
array("label"=> "2011", "y"=> 70.55),
array("label"=> "2012", "y"=> 72.50),
array("label"=> "2013", "y"=> 81.30),
array("label"=> "2014", "y"=> 63.60),
array("label"=> "2015", "y"=> 69.38),
array("label"=> "2016", "y"=> 98.70)
);
?>
```

My `JS`

```
<?PHP
$script = <<< JS
window.onload = function () {
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer1", {
animationEnabled: true,
theme: "light2",
title:{
    text: "Average Amount Spent on Real and Artificial X-Mas Trees in U.S."
},
legend:{
    cursor: "pointer",
    verticalAlign: "center",
    horizontalAlign: "right",
    itemclick: toggleDataSeries
},
data: [{
    type: "column",
    name: "Real Trees",
    indexLabel: "{y}",
    yValueFormatString: "$#0.##",
    showInLegend: true
    dataPoints: <?php echo json_encode($dataPoints1, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>
},{
    type: "column",
    name: "Artificial Trees",
    indexLabel: "{y}",
    yValueFormatString: "$#0.##",
    showInLegend: true,
    dataPoints: <?php echo json_encode($dataPoints2, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>
}]
});
chart.render();

function toggleDataSeries(e){
if (typeof(e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible) {
    e.dataSeries.visible = false;
}
else{
    e.dataSeries.visible = true;
}
chart.render();
}
}

JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
?>
```

When I run my code I am getting below error

> Array to string conversion

This error comes at `dataPoints: <?php echo json_encode($dataPoints1, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>`

How can I rid of this error? Any help would hi highly appreciated

Comment: Is the missing `,` before first `dataPoints:..` a typo?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava adding `,` won't make any difference

Comment: can you mark the answer if it worked for you

Answer (score 1):

You should encode the php array to json outside the heredoc and supply the output to the javascript part, and you dont use the php tags but use curly braces `{}` to parse values from the variable inside the heredoc.

See below it should work correctly

```
<?PHP
$dataPoints1 = json_encode($dataPoints1, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
$dataPoints2 = json_encode($dataPoints1, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

$script = <<< JS
window.onload = function () {
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer1", {
animationEnabled: true,
theme: "light2",
title:{
    text: "Average Amount Spent on Real and Artificial X-Mas Trees in U.S."
},
legend:{
    cursor: "pointer",
    verticalAlign: "center",
    horizontalAlign: "right",
    itemclick: toggleDataSeries
},
data: [{
    type: "column",
    name: "Real Trees",
    indexLabel: "{y}",
    yValueFormatString: "$#0.##",
    showInLegend: true
    dataPoints: {$dataPoints1}
},{
    type: "column",
    name: "Artificial Trees",
    indexLabel: "{y}",
    yValueFormatString: "$#0.##",
    showInLegend: true,
    dataPoints: {$dataPoints2}
}]
});
chart.render();

function toggleDataSeries(e){
if (typeof(e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible) {
    e.dataSeries.visible = false;
}
else{
    e.dataSeries.visible = true;
}
chart.render();
}
}

JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Faisal, You are passing a String(echo prints anything as strings) in "dataPoints" but its accepts JSON Array.

You need to parse the json string to convert it into a valid JSON. Use JSON.parse() function and modify your code in Javascript as below.

dataPoints: JSON.parse()

**Updated:**

First take the dataPoints from PHP in a variable before initialising the chart. Then pass this variable within chart configuration. Also try with JSON.parse().

If it still doesn't work, print this new variable in Console and check your output and post that here

Comment: See this answer please. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21153859/7867822

Comment: First take the dataPoints from PHP in a variable before initialising the chart. Then pass this variable within chart configuration. Also try with JSON.parse(). 

If it still doesn't work, print this new variable in Console and check your output and post that here

Comment: I'm not the asker :) Just pointing out that OP's method is possible, your answer states incorrect info

Comment: `var dp1 = <?php echo json_encode( $dataPoints1 ) ?>;

console.log(dp1);` still gives me same error

Comment: same is the case with JSON.parse